# How to get richtextbox lines?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get richtextbox lines without displaying the content on it,  I have a code like this under the button2

```
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
  richTextBox2.Text* += split[i] + "\n";
  MessageBox.Show("Tamam!");`
```

but it takes too much time to display the content on Richtext, If I did not use this code above, there have another code under the button3 which is related with the code above

```
          foreach (string line in *richTextBox2.Lines*)
```

how should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: As you are looping the whole text it takes time to display what ever you need. Break the loop when your required text or line was captured

Comment: Between what you are trying to achieve you didn't say

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what you exactly want to achieve but if updating of the control takes a lot of time you might try before to start the loop in buton2 to stop rendering the control. Don't forget to enable it again.

Like so:

```
richtextBox2.SuspendLayout();
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
{
  richTextBox2.Text* += split[i] + "\n";   
}
MessageBox.Show("Tamam!");
richtexbox2.ResumeLayout();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx

Or buildup your string with a stringbuilder first and the assign:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
{
  builder.Append(split[i]);
  builder.Append('\n');   
}
richTextBox2.Text = builder.ToString();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9sxk6fy.aspx